# Passing PDF to php to send in email

Tags: php, ajax

i'm using an API to return a PDF. The php file that returns the PDF is "getndadata.php" and this is the response :
[image]

I'm then passing that response via ajax to another php file called sendpdf.This is the response.. (i know its getting the pdf data because its in the response text)

[image]

this is my code in "sendpdf.php"

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];

include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$account="XXX";
$password="XXX";
$to='XXX';
$from="XXX";
$from_name="XXX";
$msg='test';
$subject="NDA Recieved";

/*End Config*/

if(!empty($_POST['data'])){

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->addStringAttachment($data, 'NDA.pdf');
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username= $account;
$mail->Password= $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName= $from_name;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->addAddress($to);
if(!$mail->send()){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('data:' => $mail->ErrorInfo));
}else{
 echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
}
}
} else {
 echo json_encode(array('data' => 'no data sent'));
}
exit();

?>
```

Is there something i need to do with

> $_POST['data'];

?

This is my ajax call :

```
var serverurl = 'XXXX/getnda.php?url=' + "<?php echo $url ?>&" + "<?php echo $ip ?>" ;
    console.log("severurl : " + serverurl);

    var response = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: serverurl,
      cache: false,
      complete: function(data){
     var fdata = JSON.stringify(data);
         once = true;

                        var serverurl2 = 'http://XXXXX/sendpdf.php';

                            $.ajax({
                              method: "POST",
                              url: serverurl2,
                              data: {data: fdata},
                            }).done(function(data){
                               console.log(data);
                               console.log("email should be sent");
                            });

      }
    });
```

Comment: You will have to show _how_ you implemented that AJAX call.

Comment: What he said ^^

Comment: Edited it to show AJAX @arkascha. That section of it seems tobe working fine though its more of the encoding anddecoding of the pdf data. I get sent a pdf via email itjust says "unable to view"

Comment: Well, if you have a PDF document and you `JSON.stringify()` that, then the result certainly is _not_ a PDF document any more, but a JSON encoded string.

Comment: Yes but then decoded at the other end?

Comment: Unless i strinfiy it i get TypeError: a is undefined